# How to pass 2d array as multiprocessing.Array to multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

My aim is to pass a parent array to `mp.Pool` and fill it with `2`s while distributing it to different processes. This works for arrays of 1 dimension:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools


def worker_function(i=None):
    global arr
    val = 2
    arr[i] = val
    print(arr[:])


def init_arr(arr=None):
    globals()['arr'] = arr

def main():
    arr = mp.Array('i', np.zeros(5, dtype=int), lock=False)
    mp.Pool(1, initializer=init_arr, initargs=(arr,)).starmap(worker_function, zip(range(5)))
    print(arr[:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

But how can I do the same for x-dimensional arrays? Adding a dimension to `arr`:

```
arr = mp.Array('i', np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int), lock=False)
```

produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/test2.py", line 17, in main
    arr = mp.Array('i', np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int), lock=False)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\anaconda3\envs\RL_framework\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 141, in Array
    ctx=self.get_context())
  File "C:\Users\Artur\anaconda3\envs\RL_framework\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 88, in Array
    obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\anaconda3\envs\RL_framework\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 67, in RawArray
    result.__init__(*size_or_initializer)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Changing the `dtype` of `arr` does not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly use [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) as a 2-d array, but in one-dimensional memory, the second dimension is just an illusion anyway :).

Luckily numpy allows reading an array from [buffer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) and reshaping it without the need to copy it. In the demo below I just use a separate lock so we can observe the changes made step by step, there's currently no race condition for what it's doing.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np    

def worker_function(i):
    global arr, arr_lock
    val = 2
    with arr_lock:
        arr[i, :i+1] = val
        print(f"{mp.current_process().name}\n{arr[:]}")


def init_arr(arr, arr_lock=None):
    globals()['arr'] = np.frombuffer(arr, dtype='int32').reshape(5, 5)
    globals()['arr_lock'] = arr_lock


def main():
    arr = mp.Array('i', np.zeros(5 * 5, dtype='int32'), lock=False)
    arr_lock = mp.Lock()

    mp.Pool(2, initializer=init_arr, initargs=(arr, arr_lock)).map(
        worker_function, range(5)
    )

    arr = np.frombuffer(arr, dtype='int32').reshape(5, 5)
    print(f"{mp.current_process().name}\n{arr}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
ForkPoolWorker-1
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
ForkPoolWorker-2
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
ForkPoolWorker-1
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
ForkPoolWorker-2
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
ForkPoolWorker-1
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 0]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]
MainProcess
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 0]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```